# Prevent white space from showing on Crystal Report with suppressed page footer

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am maintaining a billing application written in ASP.NET 3.5 in VS2008.  Invoices are crystal reports using the crystal reports that comes with VS2008.

The front page of my invoice has a number of graphics at the top and bottom, in particular the front page graphic footer is flush with the bottom of the page.

The customer has now requested that page footers be added to the invoice.  I've added a simple page footer with page numbers and a separating line.  I've also set it suppress the footer on page 1.

The problem is the space the page footer would occupying is still visible as white space on the front page, breaking the invoice layout.  I have set "Reserve Minimum Page Footer" and "Suppress Blank Section" and both have no effect.  From my research it appears that there is no solution in this version of crystal reports.

Has anyone else had this problem and found a solution that didn't require a new version of crystal reports?

Currently I've gone with adding page numbers to the page header and that works ok.  I tried the recommendations http://www.crystalkeen.com/articles/crystalreports/pagebreaksconditional.htm, found from another SO question but that didn't work.  My report doesn't display a details section.  It displays the front page in the header and the details pages are sub reports in footers.

Answer (score 0):

Suppress blank does not always work. In the Format Section properties for that section, click on the conditional suppression button (X+2) and use something like the following:

```
If OnFirstPage Then
   True
Else
   False
```

That tells it to set Suppress=True on the first page.

If I misread your question, let me know. It's fixable though.

Comment: Also, just a tip... some users get confused as to what is actually showing up on the report as white space. It's REAL easy to know what section one is looking at. Just look to the left of the white space in the section area for the name and/or abbreviation of the section. This will always tell you what you're looking at.

Comment: the above is the same as 'pageNumber = 1' for the suppress formula, which is what I do.  The problem is crystal reserves white space for the largest footer, regardless of whether it's displayed or not.  From my research my options are simply update to a later version of crystal eg 11, which I'm not prepared to do. I've also used logic to detect first page (given I'm printing multiple 'first pages' in the one report). I get the same white space issue.  In the end I gave up and told the customer it's not possible and they accepted a compromise and page numbers are now in the header.

Comment: Did you ever try splitting the Page Footer section to see if it would make a difference? Also, putting the details subreports in the page footer section is not the right location. If you're linking to data of any sort in the main report, you should be grouping data at least one time. If you've got a least one group, your sub-reports should be in the Group Footer section.

Comment: And if your data does not need to be grouped and it's only manipulating one set of data, the page header section would function EXACTLY like the page footer section. They have the exact same "job"; just one is at top of page, one at bottom.

Comment: I tried all of those things CDTX.  No joy.  As far as I was able to ascertain, this is a documented limitation within Crystal and was added to a later version.

Answer (score 0):

page footer defaultly as some space on every page.
So try to put content of page footer in detail section and conditionally invoke it.